# Syntax Error - unexpected tASSOC expecting tCOLON2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Using stiki gem from [here](https://github.com/mguymon/stiki#readme)

In the Stiki Configuration part, it says you can make it authenticate for certain pages like this.

```
stiki.authenticate_pages = :all   # other options are :only => [actions]  or :except => [actions]
```

What i've tried is to do

```
stiki.authenticate_pages, :only => [:new]
```

But i get this error below

```
C:\Users\X\Documents\GitHub\X>rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.8 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/act
ive_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load': C:/Users/X/Documents/GitHub/X/config/initializers/stiki.rb:10: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting tC
OLON2 or '[' or '.' (SyntaxError)
...ki.authenticate_pages, :only => [:new]  # other options are ...
...                               ^
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
stiki.authenticate_pages = {:only => [:new]}
```

or

```
stiki.authenticate_pages :only => [:new]
```

Comment: Thanks stiki.authenticate_pages = {:only => [:new]} works, I will mark as answered in 5mins